# not logging into desired page after login

Tags: php

I want to login using login page and if username and password is correct then it should load the page.My controller is as follows

```
class adminlogin extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library(array('session','encrypt'));
        $this->load->helper('url'); 
        $this->load->model('adminloginmodel','',true);  
    }
    function index()
    {

        $this->load->view('adminlogin');
    }
    function checkuser()
    {
        //$this->userId();
        $username=$this->input->post('username');
        $password=$this->input->post('password');
        $str='';
        $this->session->set_userdata('userIdAdmin',$username);

/**************************md5 password*****************************/

        $passMd5=base64_encode($password);

/**************************md5 password*****************************/       
        $data['login']=$this->adminloginmodel->adminlogin($username,$passMd5);
        if($data['login']->num_rows()>0)
        {


            $this->load->view('stockpointheader');

        }
        else 
        {
        }


    }
```

My login page is as follows

```
<div class="main_wrap">
<!-- admin inner part start-->
<div  class="admin_main_wrap">
<div class="login_wrap">
<div class="login_wrap_bg">
<!--login header part start-->
<div class="login_header_wrap">
<div class="login_logo"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/images/logo.png" width="100" height="116" /></div>
<div class="login_header_text"> ATMINDIA STOCKPOINT LOGIN </div>
</div>
<!--login header part end-->

<!--error message start-->

<div class="login_error_wrap" id="usernamepasswordcheck">
<div class="login_error_mesg_img"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/wrong_icon.png" width="16" height="16" /></div> 
<div class="login_error_mesg_text"> Invalid username and password.</div>
<div class="login_close_img"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/icon_close.png" id="closepopup"  width="16" height="16" /></div>
</div>

<!--error message end-->
<!--login content part start-->
<div class="login_textbox_bg">
<div class="login_textbox_wrap">
<div class="login_textbox_Name"> Username :</div>
<div class="login_textbox_textfield"> 
<input name="username" id="username" type="text"  size="25"/></div>
</div>

<div class="login_textbox_wrap">
<div class="login_textbox_Name"> Password :</div>
<div class="login_textbox_textfield"> 
<input name="password" id="password" type="password"  size="25"/></div>
</div>

<div class="login_textbox_wrap">
<div class="login_forget_text">  Forgot your Password ?</div>
<div class="login_btm_wrap"> 
<div class="login_btm_text_wrap" id="login" name="login"> Login </div>
</div>
</div>

<!--login content part end-->
</div>
</div>

<!-- admin login part ends-->

</div>

<!-- admin inner part ends-->
</div>
```

The page i want to go after login is as follows

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>/css/admin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- admin header part start-->
<div class="admin_header_wrap">
<div class="admin_logo"><a href=""><img src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/logo.png"  border="0"/></a></div>
<div class="admin_menu_wrap">
<!--icon part start-->
<a href="">
<div class="admin_menu_btn">
<div class="admin_icon"><img src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/dashboard_icon.png" border="0"/></div>
<div class="admin_icon_text"> DASHBOARD </div>
</div>
</a>
<!--icon part end-->

<!--icon part start-->
<a href="">
<div class="admin_menu_btn">
<div class="admin_icon"><img src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/suppl_icon.png" border="0"/></div>
<div class="admin_icon_text"> SUPPLIERS  </div>
</div>
</a>
<!--icon part end-->

<!--icon part start-->
<a href="">
<div class="admin_menu_btn">
<div class="admin_icon"><img src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/warehouse-icon.png" border="0"/></div>
<div class="admin_icon_text"> WAREHOUSE </div>
</div>
</a>
<!--icon part end-->

<!--icon part start-->
<a href="">
<div class="admin_menu_btn">
<div class="admin_icon"><img src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/Retal_icon.png" border="0"/></div>
<div class="admin_icon_text"> STOCKPOINT </div>
</div>
</a>
<!--icon part end-->


<!--icon part start-->
<a href="">
<div class="admin_menu_btn">
<div class="admin_icon"><img src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/arealeader.png" border="0"/></div>
<div class="admin_icon_text"> POS </div>
</div>
</a>
<!--icon part end-->

<!--icon part start-->
<a href="">
<div class="admin_menu_btn">
<div class="admin_icon"><img src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/mem_icon.png" border="0"/></div>
<div class="admin_icon_text"> MEMBERS </div>
</div>
</a>
<!--icon part end-->


<!--icon part start-->
<a href="">
<div class="admin_menu_btn">
<div class="admin_icon"><img src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/suppl_icon.png" border="0"/></div>
<div class="admin_icon_text"> PAYOUT </div>
</div>
</a>
<!--icon part end-->



<!--icon part start-->
<a href="">
<div class="admin_menu_btn">
<div class="admin_icon"><img src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/suppl_icon.png" border="0"/></div>
<div class="admin_icon_text"> REPORTS </div>
</div>
</a>
<!--icon part end-->
</div>
</div>
<!-- admin headr part ends-->
```

and my model is as follows

```
 function adminlogin($username,$passMd5)
        {



 $password= base64_decode($passMd5);

         $sql="SELECT user_id,password,role FROM atm_login WHERE user_id='$username' AND password='$password' AND role='stockpoint' ";
        $query=$this->db->query($sql);

        return $query;
        }
```

Now my problem is that i am able to see the page in firebug but it is not displaying in the page.Please help me

Comment: You know, base64 != md5. Not even close.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by @Truth:

Change these

Remove this in your controller:

```
$passMd5=base64_encode($password);
```

And change `$passMd5` to `$password` in this line:

```
$data['login']=$this->adminloginmodel->adminlogin($username,$password);
```

Change this in your model:

```
$password= md5($passMd5);
```

Comment: no my problem is that im not able to go to that stockpointheader view page.but im able to see the same page in firebug but  not in the browser

Comment: I see. There might be errors on that page. Do you have error_reporting disabled?

Comment: how to disable error_reporting disabled? Ihave not done anything regarding error_reporting